# pgfplots - box plot with colored outliers

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot

I am trying to restyle a pgfplots box plot in a matter suggested by [Daniel Carr](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d712/8ec89ee4423eb9215ee47a00efa7347be8c5.pdf).

- filled boxes instead of outlined
- thickened whiskers with no fences
- all elements (boxes, whiskers, and outliers) colored differently depending on if they are above or below the median.

I am almost finished except for the coloring of the outliers.  Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{
    every boxplot/.append style={
        scatter,
%        visualization depends on={((\thisrow{y}<\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{median}) ? "red" : "blue") \as \perpointcolor},
        % scatter/use mapped color={draw=\perpointcolor,fill=\perpointcolor},
        boxplot/draw/box/.code={
            \draw [/pgfplots/boxplot/every box/.try,
                   /pgfplots/boxplot/every lower box/.try]
                (boxplot box cs:\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{lower quartile},0)
                rectangle
                (boxplot box cs:\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{median},1); 
            \draw [/pgfplots/boxplot/every box/.try,
                   /pgfplots/boxplot/every upper box/.try]
                (boxplot box cs:\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{median},0)
                rectangle
                (boxplot box cs:\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{upper quartile},1); 
        },
        boxplot/draw/lower whisker/.code={
            \draw[/pgfplots/boxplot/every lower whisker/.try] (boxplot cs:\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{lower whisker})
              -- (boxplot cs:\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{lower quartile});
        },
        boxplot/draw/upper whisker/.code={
            \draw[/pgfplots/boxplot/every upper whisker/.try] (boxplot cs:\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{upper quartile})
              -- (boxplot cs:\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{upper whisker});
              }
        },       
    boxplot/.cd,
        every lower box/.style={draw=red,fill=red},
        every upper box/.style={draw=green,fill=green},
        every lower whisker/.style={ultra thick,draw=red},
        every upper whisker/.style={ultra thick,draw=green},
        every median/.style={black}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        y=0.33cm,
        enlarge x limits,
        ytick=\empty,
        axis y line=none,
        axis equal image,
    ]
    \addplot+[
        boxplot prepared={
            lower whisker=42, lower quartile=45,
            median=47,
            upper quartile=47.5, upper whisker=48,
            sample size=1000,
        }] table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {40\\ 34\\ 56\\};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

The two commented lines are my attempt to color the outliers depending on if they are below or above the median.  When I uncomment them I get a `Missing $ inserted` error.

I'm not sure the `scatter` keys are aware of the `boxplot prepared` key values.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out once I realized that `point meta` can include computations based on table data.  And it is even aware of the `boxplot prepared` keys!

The relevant keys are:

```
point meta=(x > \boxplotvalue{median}),
colormap={relativetomedian}{color=(red) color=(green)},
scatter/use mapped color={draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color},
```

The first line sets `point meta` to `0` or `1` depending on whether the plotted x-coordinate is less than or greater than the median.  The second line sets up a color map between the two colors (below and above median).  The third line sets the point color.  Since the point meta is either 0 or 1, the color is either the extreme left or right side of the map.

Here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass[png]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{
    every boxplot/.append style={
        scatter,
        point meta=(x > \boxplotvalue{median}),
        colormap={relativetomedian}{color=(red) color=(green)},
        scatter/use mapped color={draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color},
        boxplot/draw/box/.code={
            \draw [/pgfplots/boxplot/every box/.try,
                   /pgfplots/boxplot/every lower box/.try]
                (boxplot box cs:\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{lower quartile},0)
                rectangle
                (boxplot box cs:\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{median},1); 
            \draw [/pgfplots/boxplot/every box/.try,
                   /pgfplots/boxplot/every upper box/.try]
                (boxplot box cs:\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{median},0)
                rectangle
                (boxplot box cs:\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{upper quartile},1); 
        },
        boxplot/draw/lower whisker/.code={
            \draw[/pgfplots/boxplot/every lower whisker/.try] (boxplot cs:\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{lower whisker})
              -- (boxplot cs:\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{lower quartile});
        },
        boxplot/draw/upper whisker/.code={
            \draw[/pgfplots/boxplot/every upper whisker/.try] (boxplot cs:\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{upper quartile})
              -- (boxplot cs:\pgfplotsboxplotvalue{upper whisker});
              }
        },       
    boxplot/.cd,
        every lower box/.style={draw=none,fill=red},
        every upper box/.style={draw=none,fill=green},
        every lower whisker/.style={ultra thick,draw=red},
        every upper whisker/.style={ultra thick,draw=green},
        every median/.style={black}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        y=0.33cm,
        enlarge x limits,
        ytick=\empty,
        axis y line=none,
        axis equal image,
    ]
    \addplot+[
        boxplot prepared={
            lower whisker=42, lower quartile=45,
            median=47,
            upper quartile=47.5, upper whisker=48,
            sample size=1000,
        }] table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {40\\ 34\\ 56\\};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]